# Retriving data from hasMany table relationship

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, has-many

I have 3 tables:

Certificates, Request and Requestc

Request hasMany Requestc.
Requestc use the certificates_requests table and has `id` `request_id` and `certificate_id` coloumns.

I'm trying to retrive data from `Request` table and im trying to retrive the names of certificates associated with that Request.

I'm trying this without sucess:

```
$options['joins'] = array (
                    array( 'table' => 'certificates_requests',
                            'alias' => 'Requestc',
                            'type' => 'left',
                            'conditions' => array('Certificate.id = Requestc.certificate_id')

                    )
    );
$certidoes = $this->Request->find('all', $options);
```

My models:

```
class Certificate extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Certificate';}




class Request extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Request';

public $hasMany = array(
    'Requestc' => array(
        'foreignKey'    => 'request_id'
    )
); }



class Requestc extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Requestc';
public $belongsTo = 'Request';
public $useTable = 'certificates_requests'; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a HABTM relationship to me.

Containable behavior will solve your problem. [Read More Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

```
<?php

// Request.php // Model
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Certificate' => array(
        'className' => 'Certificate',
        'joinTable' => 'certificates_requests',
        'foreignKey' => 'request_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'certificate_id'
    )
);

// Certificate.php // Model
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Request' => array(
        'className' => 'Request',
        'joinTable' => 'certificates_requests',
        'foreignKey' => 'certificate_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'request_id'
    )
);

// RequestsController.php
$this->Request->contain(array(
    'Certificate' => array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'name')
    )
));

$request = $this->Request->read(null, <requestIdHere>);
// $request = array(
//     'Request' => array(
//          '<requestData>',
//          ...
//     ),
//     'Certificate' => array(
//          [0] => array(
//              'id'     => <idGoesHere>,
//              'name'   => "<nameGoesHere>'
//          ),
//          [1] => array(
//              'id'     => <idGoesHere>,
//              'name'   => "<nameGoesHere>'
//          ),
//          [2] => array(
//              'id'     => <idGoesHere>,
//              'name'   => "<nameGoesHere>'
//          ),
//     )
// )
?>
```

Let me know if this solves your problem. :)

-Drew

Comment: Hi!!! I got this: 
`array(
 (int) 0 => array(
  'Request' => array(
   'id' => '114',
   'motivo' => 'Licitação',
   'nome_licitacao' => 'oi',
   'nome_empresa' => '515',
   'data_pregao' => '',
   'created' => '1365641339',
   'outros' => '',
   'status' => false
  ),
  'Certificate' => array(
   (int) 0 => array(
    'nome' => '545.15',
    'CertificatesRequest' => array(
     'id' => '34',
     'request_id' => '114',
     'certificate_id' => '1'
    )
   ),`

Comment: Is that the data you expected? If so, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks. :)

Comment: And I'm trying to retrive Certificate name in a foreach!!!
My controller:
`$this->Request->contain('Certificate.nome');
 $certidoes = $this->Request->find('all');
  
   
   $this->set('certidoes', $certidoes);`
And the view:
`<?php foreach ($certidoes as $certidao): ?>
<td><?php echo $certidao['Certificate']['nome']; ?></td>`

The error: Undefined index "nome"
Thanks!!!

Comment: So, you can reference the certificate 'nome' the way you have it, if it is a hasOne or belongsTo relationship, since this is either a hasMany or hasAndBelongsToMany relationship (it was hard to tell by your OP) and could lead to the possibility of returning multiple rows, the associated 'certificates' will be numerically indexed for each row returned (e.g. `certidao['Certificate'][#][array]`, where # is the index of the certificate you want), for example: `<?php foreach ($certidao['Certificate'] as $certificate) { echo $certificate['nome']; } ?>`

Comment: Does any Request ever have more than one certificate at a time?

Comment: Yep, then you would access each certificate via certidao['Certifacte'][#].  Please mark the answer as correct. :)